# read mails from custom label in gmail using python(google api)

Tags: python-3.x, api, google-api-client

I want to read mail from customed label USING PYTHON and google API.However i m getting error of change the label from inbox to customed label

```
label_id_one = 'AW'

label_id_two = 'UNREAD'

unread_msgs = GMAIL.users().messages().list(userId='me',labelIds=[label_id_one, label_id_two]).execute()
```

GETTING THIS ERROR:

```
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\googleapiclient\discovery.py", line 272, in _retrieve_discovery_doc
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=actual_url)
    googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 403 when requesting https://gmail.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v2 returned "The request cannot be identified with a project. Please pass a valid API key with the request.">
```

Comment: found any solution or answer?

Comment: No still looking for

Comment: i got the solution

Comment: i have removed labelIDs and added q paramter as shown below.Here test is the folder created by me in gmail.
 unread_msgs = GMAIL.users().messages().list(userId='me',q='in:test is:unread').execute()

Answer (score 3):

I have removed labelIDs and added q parameter as shown below. Here the "test" is the folder created by me in Gmail.

```
unread_msgs = GMAIL.users().messages().list(userId='me',q='in:test is:unread').execute()
```